# AngularJS does not recognize URL changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, hyperlink

Sometimes when I change the URL via an a-tag's `href` attribute or via `$location.url`, angularjs does not fire a `$locationChangeStart` event.

The only way to solve this, is by reloading the whole page with the new URL but in a SPA this is more or less nonsense.

Does anybody knows how to fix this issue.

I can't show you much code, because it's only `<a href="new url">Blabla</a>`

When I click it, the url changes but the view stays the same.

Update: I noticed that the event is fired, but the the routeprovider does not load the controller.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: In a normal scenario then AngularJS `$locationChangeStart` event should fire every time the URL change. Can you provide the version, modules and some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you using ui-router? Can you provide your routing configuration and your html file?

Comment: I don't use Ui-Router. Only the basic router-provider.

Comment: I can't give you code, because there is no specific part in the code where this issue occures.
It also occures when I click the page back button.

Comment: @JohannesScharf So just give us one part of the code where it showscases the `$locationChangeStart` not firing?